# Debugging with Docker PhpStorm and Xdebug - missing .env variables

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, phpstorm, fpm

I am using `.env` file and `docker-compose` together with: `php:8.2.3-fpm` image.
In order for ENV variables to be visible in the PHP script, I've had to add: `clear_env=no` to `php-fpm.conf` file.

Everything works nicely, however the issue I am having is that when I set up Xdebug from PhpStorm to debug PHP script (using remote SSH interpreter to my Docker FPM container) I can't see the `.env` variables.

When I SSH into the container and try to print out the ENV variable, e.g.: `php -r 'print getenv("POSTGRES_PASS");'` it's printed correctly. It's only an issue when running an Xdebug session from the PhpStorm.

When Xdebug session is initiated through browser (`XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM`) then env variables are available correctly.

I am wondering if there is any `PhpStorm` or `XDebug` cli setting which explicitly cleans/ignores environmental variables.
They're clearly available inside of the container.

Any hints very much appreciated !
Thanks

Comment: There is no option on PhpStorm side that is responsible for the behaviour. By the way, I have tried to reproduce with a simpler example (no php-fpm) and it seems to be env vars work fine out of box with the CLI debugging. Is there any specific reason why would you use your interpreter as remote SSH not Docker Compose type?

Comment: @duck_in_hat Thanks for trying it out. I use remote SSH, so I can use container that's already running on my local instead of spinning up a new one via `docker-compose`. I've used that for years and remember that speed of `docker-compose` debugging wasn't great, especially when dealt with huge monolithic containers. With debugging you usually need quick feedback loop to stay productive.
I am going to give a normal `php` container a go to rule out `fpm` issues and will definitely try `docker-compose` debugging again. Thanks !